# Does this condition implies compactness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

This question was part of my analysis quiz and I was unable to solve 1 option out of 4. So, I am asking it here.

> If A is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that there is no 1-1 and continuous function from A onto (0,1) then is A compact?

I am unable to think Of which result I should use to approach the problem (option). SO, please guide me.

I studied point set topology from Stephen Abott understanding analysis.

Comment: $A=\mathbb N$ is an obvious counter-example.

Comment: $A=[0,1)$ is another counterexample.